# How to put variable inside a string which is inside a "link_to" tag in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I would like to make a link with a background-image in my project. It would allow me to get a clickable picture with good proportions.

Here is the best I can get until now :

```
<%= link_to "", show_item_general_path(item), html_options = {:class => "picture", :style => "background-image: url( asset_url(item.asset_files.first.image )); background-position: 50% 50%; background-size: cover;"} %>
```

html result:

```
<a class="picture" href="/items/1" style="background-image: url( asset_url(item.asset_files.first.image )); background-position: 50% 50%; background-size: cover;"></a>
```

My helper doesn't get interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `#{asset_url(item.asset_files.first.image )}` for string interpolation.

```
<%= link_to "", show_item_general_path(item), html_options = {:class => "picture", :style => "background-image: url( #{asset_url(item.asset_files.first.image)} ); background-position: 50% 50%; background-size: cover;"} %>
```

You may want to try this (you may need to tweak css/style):

```
<%= link_to show_item_general_path(item), :class => "picture" do %>
  <%= image_tag item.asset_files.first.image %>
<% end %>
```